# Compensation for Hotel or Travel Package

Tags: international-travel, hotels, compensation

Are there platforms similar to [www.flightright.de](https://flightright.de) that provide support to get compensation for hotel or travel package bookings in case of issues?

I am aware of some websites but they just redirect you to third party attorneys.

Comment: I think it's unlikely. Most of those websites only deal with **set-amount** compensation claims under EU261, which in most cases the information needed is publicly available (flight schedules and changes etc.). That's why it's profitable for them: they just need to generate form letters and there are only so many airlines.

Comment: There is no such thing for package travels. Each case must be dealt specifically and possible reasons for compensation are myriad, and there are countless organizers who sell products with countless versions of conditions = no largely automated help available.